# D3.js Bars not showing up

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

Hi I am trying to recreate this bar chart from here -->
http://bl.ocks.org/godds/ec089a2cf3e06a2cd5fc
but My bars are not showing up and I am pretty sure that i have given right values to the y and height.

Can someone please help me with this ?

My csv file is in this format -->

```
Day,Time,Trips  //Ignore time column.
2015-01-01,13,17448
2015-01-01,14,17994
2015-01-01,15,18279
2015-01-01,16,16602
2015-01-01,17,17511
2015-01-01,18,18082
2015-01-01,19,16485
2015-01-01,20,15017
2015-01-01,21,14801
2015-01-01,22,14005
2015-01-01,23,11610
2015-01-02,00,9388
2015-01-02,01,6291
2015-01-02,02,4027
2015-01-02,03,2905
2015-01-02,04,2626
2015-01-02,05,2755
2015-01-02,06,5811
2015-01-02,07,8256
2015-01-02,08,10946
2015-01-02,09,13373
2015-01-02,10,15243
2015-01-02,11,16999
2015-01-02,12,19252
2015-01-02,13,19023
2015-01-02,14,20260
2015-01-02,15,20429
2015-01-02,16,18223
2015-01-02,17,20680
2015-01-02,18,23008
2015-01-02,19,23227
2015-01-02,20,20153
2015-01-02,21,19611
2015-01-02,22,21722
2015-01-02,23,21088
2015-01-03,00,19467
2015-01-03,01,16660
2015-01-03,02,13607
2015-01-03,03,10620
2015-01-03,04,7061
2015-01-03,05,3512
2015-01-03,06,4120
2015-01-03,07,5216
2015-01-03,08,7908
2015-01-03,09,11869
2015-01-03,10,14975
2015-01-03,11,17966
2015-01-03,12,21644
2015-01-03,13,23718
2015-01-03,14,24143
2015-01-03,15,23494
2015-01-03,16,20350
2015-01-03,17,22295
2015-01-03,18,25305
2015-01-03,19,25667
2015-01-03,20,20531
2015-01-03,21,21399
2015-01-03,22,22409
2015-01-03,23,22833
2015-01-04,00,20632
2015-01-04,01,17494
2015-01-04,02,13485
2015-01-04,03,9842
2015-01-04,04,6384
```

My HTML file-->

```
 `<!DOCTYPE html>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <style>
        .axis {
          font: 10px sans-serif;
        }
        .axis path,
    .axis line {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #000;
      shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }
    .brush .extent {
      stroke: #fff;
      fill-opacity: .125;
      shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }
</style>
<body>
<script src="D3/d3.min.js"></script>
<script>

    // sizing information, including margins so there is space for labels, etc
    var margin =  { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 100, left: 40 },
        width = 1800 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
        marginOverview = { top: 430, right: margin.right, bottom: 20,  left: margin.left },
        heightOverview = 500 - marginOverview.top - marginOverview.bottom;

    // set up a date parsing function for future use
    var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d").parse;

    // some colours to use for the bars
    var colour = d3.scale.ordinal()
                        .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);

    // mathematical scales for the x and y axes
    var x = d3.time.scale()
                    .range([0, width]);
    var y = d3.scale.linear()
                    .range([height, 0]);
    var xOverview = d3.time.scale()
                    .range([0, width]);
    var yOverview = d3.scale.linear()
                    .range([heightOverview, 0]);

    // rendering for the x and y axes
    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                    .scale(x)
                    .orient("bottom");
    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                    .scale(y)
                    .orient("left");
    var xAxisOverview = d3.svg.axis()
                    .scale(xOverview)
                    .orient("bottom");

    // something for us to render the chart into
    var svg = d3.select("body")
                    .append("svg") // the overall space
                        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);
    var main = svg.append("g")
                    .attr("class", "main")
                    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
    var overview = svg.append("g")
                        .attr("class", "overview")
                        .attr("transform", "translate(" + marginOverview.left + "," + marginOverview.top + ")");

    // brush tool to let us zoom and pan using the overview chart
    var brush = d3.svg.brush()
                        .x(xOverview)
                        .on("brush", brushed);

    // setup complete, let's get some data!
    d3.csv("trips.csv", parse, function(data) {

        // data ranges for the x and y axes
        x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
        y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.total; })]);
        xOverview.domain(x.domain());
        yOverview.domain(y.domain());

        // data range for the bar colours
        // (essentially maps attribute names to colour values)
      //  colour.domain(d3.keys(data[0]));

        // draw the axes now that they are fully set up
        main.append("g")
            .attr("class", "x axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(xAxis);
        main.append("g")
            .attr("class", "y axis")
            .call(yAxis);
        overview.append("g")
            .attr("class", "x axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + heightOverview + ")")
            .call(xAxisOverview);

        // draw the bars. Here is the main Problem i guess..
        main.append("g")
                .attr("class", "bars")
            // a group for each stack of bars, positioned in the correct x position
            .selectAll(".bar.stack")
            .data(data)
            .enter().append("g")
                .attr("class", "bar stack")
                .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.date) + ",0)"; })
            // a bar for each value in the stack, positioned in the correct y positions
            .selectAll("rect")
            .data(function(d) { return d.total; })
            .enter().append("rect")
                .attr("class", "bar")
                .attr("width", 6)
                .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.total); })
                .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.total) ;})
        //console.log(data);

        overview.append("g")
                    .attr("class", "bars")
            .selectAll(".bar")
            .data(data)
            .enter().append("rect")
                .attr("class", "bar")
                .attr("x", function(d) { return xOverview(d.date) - 3; })
                .attr("width", 6)
                .attr("y", function(d) { return yOverview(d.total); })
                .attr("height", function(d) { return heightOverview - yOverview(d.total); });

        // add the brush target area on the overview chart
        overview.append("g")
                    .attr("class", "x brush")
                    .call(brush)
                    .selectAll("rect")
                        // -6 is magic number to offset positions for styling/interaction to feel right
                        .attr("y", -6)
                        // need to manually set the height because the brush has
                        // no y scale, i.e. we should see the extent being marked
                        // over the full height of the overview chart
                        .attr("height", heightOverview + 7);  // +7 is magic number for styling

    });

    // by habit, cleaning/parsing the data and return a new object to ensure/clarify data object structure
    function parse(d) {
        var value = { date: parseDate(d.Day) }; // turn the date string into a date object

        // adding calculated data to each count in preparation for stacking

        value.total = +d.Trips
        return value;
    }

    // zooming/panning behaviour for overview chart
    function brushed() {
        // update the main chart's x axis data range
        x.domain(brush.empty() ? xOverview.domain() : brush.extent());
        // redraw the bars on the main chart
        main.selectAll(".bar.stack")
                .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.date) + ",0)"; })
        // redraw the x axis of the main chart
        main.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
    }

</script>
</body>`
```

Comment: do you also see something like this? https://plnkr.co/edit/ouXS42g8JRPfo4IRN66g?p=preview

Comment: I have all the bars on the overview chart but not on the main chart.

Comment: Its exactly like this - > https://plnkr.co/edit/ouXS42g8JRPfo4IRN66g?p=preview

Comment: May be they are. That;s why 'y' and 'width' attributes are not getting populated.
Please help.

Comment: the problem is your rects are not getting appended inside the `<g class="bar stack">` . So my best bet is that `.data(function(d) {return d.total; })` is wrong. Because even if you do `.attr("width", function(d) {console.log(1); return 6; })` you can't see the console.log

Comment: So how to fix that ? I tried putting `return d;` . But that didn't work also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK here's the result: https://plnkr.co/edit/ouXS42g8JRPfo4IRN66g?p=preview

I've changed your parse function to

```
function parse(d) {
        var value = { date: parseDate(d.Day) }; // turn the date string into a date object
        // adding calculated data to each count in preparation for stacking

        value.total = +d.Trips
        value.counts = [{y0:0,y1:value.total}];
        return value;
    }
```

Because in

```
.data(function(d) {return d.total; })
```

it is expecting d.total to be an array and it wasn't. So I changed it with the

```
.data(function(d) {return d.counts; })
```

which I defined in the parse function. And I made small adjustments to height and y accordingly:

```
 .attr("y", function(d) {return y(d.y1); })
                .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.y0) - y(d.y1);})
```